# Empty file after Intellij crashed

Tags: intellij-idea

I have worked on one page for about three days and totally forgot to put it on git. Intellij crashed, and I did not notice that the content is missing because I started to work at different place, so the local history does not contain the file.

But there is a light of hope - I got this message from Intellij:

> This document contains very long lines Soft wraps forcibly enabled to improve editor

However, the file is seems empty.

Answer (score 4):

Try to restore the file using IntelliJ's [Local History](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/using-local-history.html).